# hover buttons background image change not working

Tags: css

### Background

I'm trying to make a menu, you hover over the button and the background image shifts its Y position to give you the 'over' effect for each button.

### CSS

```
.menu {float: left;}
.menu span {display: none;}
.menu a {display: block; margin: 10px; width: 200px; height: 50px;}
#itemA {background: url('images/btnA.png') no-repeat 0 0;}
#itemB {background: url('images/btnB.png') no-repeat 0 0;}
#itemC {background: url('images/btnC.png') no-repeat 0 0;}
#itemD {background: url('images/btnD.png') no-repeat 0 0;}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<a id="itemA" href="#"><span>AAAAA</span></a>
<a id="itemB" href="#"><span>BBBBB</span></a>
<a id="itemC" href="#"><span>CCCCC</span></a>
<a id="itemD" href="#"><span>DDDDD</span></a>
</div>
```

### Problem

why do none of these work?

```
/*** - test A     
a.menu:link {background-position: 0 -51px;}
a.menu:visited {display: block; margin: 10px; width: 200px; height: 32px;}
***/

/*** - test B     
a.menu:hover {background-position: 0 -51px;}
***/

/*** - test C    
.menu a:hover {background-position: 0 -51px;}
***/

/*** - test D     
.menu:hover a {background-position: 0 -51px;}
***/

/*** - test E     
a:hover .menu {background-position: 0 -51px;}
***/
```

### Notes

images are 200x101px (50px high with a 1px seperator)

(edit) I know the following works, but im not trying to do it liek that

```
#itemA {background-image: url('images/btnA.png');}
#itemB {background-image: url('images/btnB.png');}
#itemC {background-image: url('images/btnC.png');}
#itemD {background-image: url('images/btnD.png');}
```

### Question

why do none of these work, should any of them work, is there a solution im missing?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-image` instead:

```
#itemA {background-image: url('images/btnA.png');}
#itemB {background-image: url('images/btnB.png');}
#itemC {background-image: url('images/btnC.png');}
#itemD {background-image: url('images/btnD.png');}
```

Or change your hover:

```
#itemA:hover, #itemB:hover, #itemC:hover, #itemD:hover {
    background-position: 0 -51px;
}
```

The problem with your code is that `#itemA` is more specific than `.menu a.menu:hover` or any other combination you have on your tests. So even if you specify the hover effect the browser will ignore it unless you remove the background position that you use on `background` or make your hover clause more specific.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say, i know that works, but i want to make it work without doing that.

Comment: yeah, theres workarounds for it, but it still doesn't answer why testC doesnt do it. im just curious to find this out. thanks for the good answers so far and so quickly.

Comment: so CSS is just picky :S oh well, thus is all real code i guess.

Comment: CSS is just a **Cascading** Style Sheet :P